# How to combine facebooksdk and socialframework?

Tags: facebook-sdk-3.1

For example, currently I am using socialframework.

Now I want to add a feature. Everytime user click the recommend button I want the user to post stuffs on his wall. I don't think it can be done with social.framework without displaying the message first.

So I want to use facebook sdk for that.

But how does the facebook sdk "know" that I already login to facebook with social framework, for example.